# Source bashrc from script failing

Tags: bash, shell

I've written a simple bash script that adds an alias to my .bashrc automatically, and when it finishes, I would like it to source the .bashrc

It works fine as of now, for example

```
./addalias.sh ls 'ls -l'
```

properly appends 'alias ls='ls -l' to the .bashrc, but doesn't source it.

The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
FIRST=$1

SECOND=${2:-cd `pwd`}

echo alias $FIRST="'$SECOND'" >> /home/oscar/.bashrc
echo alias $FIRST="'$SECOND'"

source /home/oscar/.bashrc
```

That doesn't work, nor does running an alias ("sourcebash") to source the bash instead of the last line.

Any thoughts on how this could be fixed?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, your script will fork a shell process and it is being sourced there. When the script is finished, any changes to that shell are gone too. I don't know of an any way around this, but maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Unrelated, you can replace the `if` statement with `SECOND=${2:-cd \`pwd\`}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell that runs 'addalias.sh' does source the `.bashrc` file; it then exits.  It does not and cannot affect the parent shell's environment.

You'd have to invoke the command as:

```
source ./addalias.sh ls 'ls --color=auto'
```

Or:

```
. ./addalias.sh ls 'ls --color=auto'
```

(*Now fixed:* And I'm not convinced that, even in a question, playing with `sudo rm -fr /*` is remotely sensible.  There's too much risk of an idiot copying and not realizing.)

Comment: That is true. Fixed, thanks.  
Is there perhaps a way to write a function that sources the .bashrc in all shells?

Comment: No; each shell is independent and would have to source the .bashrc separately.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make it a function or an alias instead of a bash script. Doing that might cause the changes to occur in the same shell.

Answer (score 0):

i'd make an alias which calls this 'addalias' script, then sources the newly-modified file.

something like

```
alias really_add_alias="addalias.sh; . .bashrc"
```

Comment: It must be a function, otherwise the script wont not get its arguments (sourcing of .bashrc will)

Comment: Like this: `addalias() { addalias.sh "$@"; . ~/.bashrc; }`

Comment: And yes, put the _function_ in your .bashrc too. And I would suggest you'd better add the aliases to some other file, not your `.bashrc`. Just to be on a safe side. Less to source from that `addalias()` function, too

Comment: The function does the same as the alias, still not sourcing it, though.  It properly appends the text to the .bashrc